# How to export feed for any account in PDF Format

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having one requirement to export feed for any account in pdf format.
So Firstly I create custom button and wrote content source as URl and in formula field pasted this link

```
[{!URLFOR('/apex/ExportFeed?id=' + Account.Id )}]
```

And after that create one VF.

```
<apex:page standardController="account" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Export Results" >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account}" var="a">
           <apex:column value="{!a.ID}"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <apex:column value="{!a.AccountNumber}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>            
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But in this code I am getting error saying

> "Visualforce Error:- Expression value does not resolve to a field"

Can any one have solution for this requirement.

Comment: When are you receiving the error?

Comment: I am able to export the account details in pdf format perfectly with the same code.

Comment: But page block table expects value to be a collection, and here it is only a single record, thats why may fail

Comment: when I am clicking on button.. It opens new page and showing this error.. Even no value is coming with particular error

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate what I have done.

1. Below is the custom button that I created (absolutely same as you have)

[image]

2. Added the button on the Account page layout

[image]

3. Results are shown below

[image]

My VF page is the same as you have mentioned, but just for argument sake posting it here as well

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="account" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Export Results" >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account}" var="a">
           <apex:column value="{!a.ID}"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <apex:column value="{!a.AccountNumber}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>            
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I need to display all feeds record related to this particular account. which is not fulfilled with this code..